# Multivariate t vs independent Cauchy random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

If I have $X,Y\stackrel{\text{iid}}\sim \text{Cauchy}$ so
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}
$$
and identically for $f_Y$ then I should have
$$
f_{XY}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\pi^2 (1+x^2)(1+y^2)}.
$$

But the pdf of a central multivariate $t$ distribution with one degree of freedom is
$$
f_t(x; \Sigma, p) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{p+1}2\right)}{\pi^{(p+1)/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}} \left[1 + x^T\Sigma^{-1}x\right]^{-(p+1)/2}
$$
([according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution)) and these two are definitely not the same no matter my choice for $\Sigma$. Why is this? Why doesn't the multivariate $t$ include the case with two independent Cauchy RVs? Why does the multivariate $t$ force some amount of dependence?

Comment: According to the same article, it is an extension of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Multivariate_Cauchy_distribution) (see the notes on independency there).

Comment: @metamorphy i did see that, but I guess my question is more about _why_. Maybe there's no satisfying answer, but I find this to be a very surprising property. It seems very weird to me that a "generalization" would lose the ability to model independent RVs